# Replace variable values which contain a certain string pattern

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this kind of data:

```
library(dplyr)
glimpse(full_dat)
Observations: 9,720
Variables: 6
$ Product <chr> "Apple iPhone 4s 8GB Unlocked GSM Smartphone w/ S...
$ Brand   <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, N...
$ Price   <dbl> 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115,...
$ Rating  <dbl> 5, 1, 4, 5, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5, 1, 5, 5, 1, 5, 2, 5, 5...
$ Reviews <chr> "It was new and at a great price! Phone came real...
$ Votes   <dbl> 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 5, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0...
```

I want to change the values of the variable `Product` in regard to the strings. For example, if the variable contains the pattern "iphone 4s" I want to change the value only to "iphone 4s".

Pseudo code:

```
glimpse(full_dat)
Observations: 9,720
Variables: 6
$ Product <chr> "iPhone 4s", "iPhone 4s", "iPhone 4s", "iphone 4s...
$ Brand   <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, N...
$ Price   <dbl> 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115,...
$ Rating  <dbl> 5, 1, 4, 5, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5, 1, 5, 5, 1, 5, 2, 5, 5...
$ Reviews <chr> "It was new and at a great price! Phone came real...
$ Votes   <dbl> 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 5, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0...
```

I read a similar post in which the following solution was suggested.

```
full_dat %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(contains('iphone 4s')), funs(.=='ipohne 4s'))
```

However, this doesn't work in my case, i.e. the values remaining the same.

Here is a small sample:

```
product = c(full_dat$Product[1:5])
dput(product)

c("Apple iPhone 4s 8GB Unlocked GSM Smartphone w/ Siri, iCloud and 8MP Camera - Black", 
"Apple iPhone 4s 8GB Unlocked GSM Smartphone w/ Siri, iCloud and 8MP Camera - Black", 
"Apple iPhone 4s 8GB Unlocked GSM Smartphone w/ Siri, iCloud and 8MP Camera - Black", 
"Apple iPhone 4s 8GB Unlocked GSM Smartphone w/ Siri, iCloud and 8MP Camera - Black", 
"Apple iPhone 4s 8GB Unlocked GSM Smartphone w/ Siri, iCloud and 8MP Camera - Black"
)
```

Comment: Can you share a version of the data with more examples of entries in the `Product` column? It's possible you could use Regex, but need some idea of consistency of structure of this column.

Comment: `stringr::str_extract(samp$Product, 'iPhone 4s')`, which returns `NA` if no match is found. thus, you can chain together a few `ifelse` statements

Comment: Questions should have *minimal* complete reproducible code.  All that is needed to show is `product <- c(...)` . Please cut this down appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for

```
library(dplyr)

samp %>%
   mutate_at(vars(Product), funs(replace(., grepl('iPhone 4s', .), 'iphone 4s')))
```

This will `replace` any `Product` that contains 'iPhone 4s' to just 'iphone 4s'.

Of course you can do this without `dplyr` as well

```
df$Product <- with(samp, replace(Product, grepl('iPhone 4s', Product),'iPhone 4s'))
```

Comment: I get: `Error in check_dot_cols(.vars, .cols) : object 'Product' not found`

Comment: @Banjo should be in `vars` or quotes. Updated the answer.